# Rewritepath and IIS Integrated Mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting

I have big issue with url-rewriting for IIS 7.0.

I've written simple module for rewriting for my NET3.5/IIS7 web application. Here is a part of the code.

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app.Request.Path.Contains("pagetorewrite.aspx"))
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("~/otherpage.aspx");
    }
```

And I register my module in web.config :

```
  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
              <add name="MyModule" type="MyModule" preCondition="" />
```

Under IIS 7.0 (Vista) using Classic ASP Pipeline it works perfect, but when I change pipeline mode to Integrated, then it stops working. There are no exceptions, errors and anything in debugger/events/logfiles - only message in a browser that page was not found. The stragnest thing is that pagename looks like mispelled or merged from parts of original page and rewrte-to page.

I've deployed my code at another computer (also vista -but x64- and iis 7.0) and it works perfect in both modes.
It looks that there's an configuration issue or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found working solution.

.NET 3.5 [TransferRequest](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2007/10/09/are-you-using-the-new-transferrequest.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: Qualify your type with the assembly name (type="MyModule,MyAssembly")

Answer (score 0):

Well, recommend you use URL Rewrite Module released by Microsoft which has been tested.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-url-rewrite-module/

Wish you enjoy it.